# Change Git Account in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I accidentally entered the credentials form an old github account the first time VSCode tried to connect when synchronizing my changes (the credentials were right for the old account, but i would like to use the new account).

Now I cannot find a way to change my account. Already tried uninstall/install, but VSCode keeps remeberming my login.

Any ideas how to refresh the given account?

Answer (score 2):

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

this will unset the git credentials for your system, Now you can use your new credentials and then enable the cache for git

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git config --system credential.helper wincred
```

this will again enable the cache for saving git password

Comment: thank you for your answer!

this does not seem to work for me :/

also if i do `git credential-manager` i get

`usage: git credential-manager [approve|clear|delete|deploy|erase|fill|get|install|reject|remove|store|uninstall|version] [<args>] fatal: Unable to open help documentation`

Comment: Try this on git bash and use the full commands mentioned above. I tried this on my system and working like a charm.

Comment: What worked for me on windows 10 is go Control Panel > Use Account > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials  Then remove existing credentials for github.com , then when you try to do git push in VSCode , it should prompt for github login , then use correct login. So changing the github connections actual lies outside of VSCode.