# Change the git account in VScode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I want to change the git account used in my VSCode. I made a new account and don't want to use the old one anymore

What I have tried so far:-

1. Did everything in this StackOverflow question [Change Git Account in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604446/change-git-account-in-vscode)
2. And in this one [Chang git account on VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882787/chang-git-account-on-vscode)
3. I also have unchecked the `GitHub Authentication` in VSCode settings!
4. Read the VSCode documentation about GitHub Integration but they don't mention such things

But I can't seem to get it to work

This is the error I get when pushing my commits

```
git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to username1/todo-app.git denied to username2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username1/todo-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `wincred` as suggested in your first link: use `manager-core` (the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) packaged with a [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)).

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

Second, make sure your Git for Windows is up-to-date ([2.35.1.windows.2 in Q2 2022](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

Third, [clean the old URL from the credential manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager-core erase
```

Note: `git-credential-manager-core.exe` is in `C:\Program Files\Git\ mingw64\libexec\git-core` folder: make sure this is part of your `%PATH%`.
Same for `printf.exe`: in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

Finally, try and push: that should trigger a popup asking for your GitHub credentials: enter the new ones.

Remember: the password must be a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), which is [mandatory since Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Comment: The first command worked but when executing the second it gives this:- ```fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered.
   Invalid input, please see 'https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential.html'```

Can you tell me where the problem is? Thanks

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi I would first validate the new account using Git in command line, with VSCode closed: try the same `git push -u origin master` from a command line. It should trigger the popup, and you would then enter the new credentials. Once that is working, open VSCode again, and go on working/committing and pushing from there.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work! Because this is literally what I have been doing for the last 2-3 days.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi What version of Git are you using on which OS?

Comment: The latest version which is 2.27.0 and Windows 10 Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Comment: `git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @johannes Good point. I have fixed the answer.